# Spring WebFlux: HttpWebHandlerAdapter - An established connection was aborted

Tags: spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am using Spring WebFlux to publish/receive Server Sent Event. On publish side, the code is as below. Then, in a test case, I loop 10 times to call "publish" to send out messages.

```
public ValidationEventPublisher() {
    this.processor = DirectProcessor.<ExternalEvent>create().serialize();
    this.sink = processor.sink();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/ssp/common/v1/eventstream", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<ServerSentEvent<ExternalEvent>> sse() {
    return processor.map(e -> ServerSentEvent.builder(e).id(String.valueOf(msgId.incrementAndGet())).build())
            .onBackpressureBuffer();
}

public void publish(ValidationEvent validationEvent)
{
    log.info("Published Validation event...");
    sink.next(validationEvent);
}
```

On receiving side, the code is:

```
final Flux<Object> stream = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl(sspUrl + "/ssp/common/v1/eventstream")
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic " + Base64Utils.encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes(UTF_8)))
            .build()
            .get()
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(ServerSentEvent.class)
            .filter(e -> e.id() != null)
            .flatMap(e -> Mono.just(e.data()))
            .doOnError(e -> handleServerDown(e))
            .repeat();

    stream.subscribe(e -> processEvent(e));
```

So, the problem is that I can only receive the first message and after that I always got an exception.

```
- Published Validation event...
- Received validation event: {"messageId":"867b5ced-...}
- Published Validation event...
- Published Validation event...
2018-09-05 11:07:43,596 ERROR [reactor-http-nio-6] [] [] 
[org.springframework.web.server.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter:213] - 
Unhandled failure: An established connection was aborted by the software in 
your host machine, response already set (status=null)
2018-09-05 11:07:43,597  WARN [reactor-http-nio-6] [] [] 
[org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter:76] - 
Handling completed with error: An established connection was aborted by the 
software in your host machine
...
```

I spent quite sometime doing some research but cannot find relevant information.
Note that I am running both sides in one test case, which means that they are in the same process and JVM. I don't think it matters but just in case.

I found the reason is a "cancellation" is sent out. But why? For example, if I add "doOnCancel" on my receiver side, I can see it is called.

Comment: please provide more code in your snippets; where does the processor comes from? Same thing for the sink?

Comment: I added more code as you requested. Thanks!

Comment: why did you add those retry/repeat operators all over the place; isn't that an infinite stream in the first place?

Comment: Neither of them matters in this question. I tried to test without them but the problem is the same.

Comment: Please check this stack overflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49967213/spring-reactive-java-io-ioexception-an-established-connection-was-aborted-by-t

Answer (score 0):

Using spring-boot-starter-parent 2.1.0.RELEASE I encountered a similar problem.
Try to run the following service on port 8080 and client on 8081

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServiceApplication {

    @Bean
    RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routes(Handler handler) {
        return route(GET("/there").and(accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)), handler::all);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Component
    class Handler {
        public Mono<ServerResponse> all(ServerRequest request) {
            Flux<String> aFlux = Flux.range(0, 1000).map(i -> UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            return ok().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM).body(aFlux, String.class);
        }
    }   
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class ClientApplication {

    @Bean
    RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routes(Handler handler) {
        return route(GET("/here").and(accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)), handler::all);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ClientApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Component
    class Handler {
        public Mono<ServerResponse> all(ServerRequest request) {
            Flux<String> resp = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080")
                                        .get()
                                        .uri("/there")
                                        .accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
                                        .retrieve()
                                        .bodyToFlux(String.class);

            return ok().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM).body(resp, String.class);
        }
    }   
}
```

Now execute curl -H "Accept: text/event-stream" "http://localhost:8081/here" a number of times and the service will sometimes error:

o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [f903e4b6] Error [java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine] for HTTP GET "/there", but ServerHttpResponse already committed (200 OK)

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since the question was posted. Now I think the problem was caused some exception when I handle the message, e.g. a NPE in processEvent. It is easy to prove this if you add a wild try...catch within processEvent.